# Class instance error whilst printing

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is essentially what I am trying to do:

```
Class MyClass():
   def __init__(self):
     self.name="Bob"
person=MyClass()
print " hello {1} how are you?".format(1=person.name)
```

This gives an error saying keyword cant be an expression
I know there are many ways around this for example:

```
print "hello " + person.name
```

But for longer sentences I prefer the first format as it is easier to understand, if anyone knows how to fix it, or even just explain to me why it is wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There should be a space between def and __init__: `def __init__(self):`

Comment: Dr Ivol t it was just an error as i typed in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print " hello {} how are you?".format(person.name)
```

if you want to use position, it begin at 0

```
print " hello {0} how are you?".format(person.name)
```

0 means the first element inside format function

```
print " {0},{1},{0}".format('a', 'b')
a,b,a
```

Comment: That's what I tried, however it came up with an error saying : "keyword cant be an expression"

Comment: @AdamCurry did you remove "1="?

Comment: @AdamCurry are you sure you removed and saved? the error you have means you give a key not in function args.  Once you remove "1=" (which is not a arg for format function), it should work

Comment: No i didn't thanks for the help, why does having the 1= part create an error though, when it doesn't if i just use strings

Comment: @AdamCurry as I mentioned, "1" is not a argument for format function